# Very few statistics people here

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Whenever I ask a statistics question, it takes people too long to comment on the question or answer it (if at all). All types of questions get answered directly except statistics questions (at least what I observed). Why is that? I asked a question about 40 minutes ago, I put in every detail so that what anyone can do is just tell me if my work is correct or not. A quick skim should really do it.

Comment: 40 minutes without an answer? Oh noes!

Comment: It's a good thing that your question here was answered in around 36 minutes.

Comment: Your experience is, perhaps, not representative of the site. In the tags I frequent it often takes a day or three (or longer) to get an answer :-)

Answer (score 10):

In that case, you may want to ask your question at the statistics site at [stats stack exchange.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: never knew such a thing existed! you're a life saver

Comment: That said, crossposting is generally frowned upon.